# disable redirect on successful login to last denied url

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot-security

I am attempting to configure spring security to perform Cookie Authentication for REST APIs as described in in this example https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/cookie-authentication/
and I have been able to achieve it with the below configuration:

```
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, AuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
            throws Exception {
        CustomAuthenticationProcessingFilter customAuthenticationProcessingFilter = new CustomAuthenticationProcessingFilter();
        customAuthenticationProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        
        
         http
         .csrf().disable()
         .addFilterAt(
                 customAuthenticationProcessingFilter,
                 UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
         .authorizeRequests()
         .antMatchers( "/**").authenticated()
         .antMatchers("/api/sign-up", "/api/sign-in").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
         .and().httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(new RestAuthenticationEntryPoint())
         .and().logout().logoutUrl("/api/sign-out");
       
        return http.build();
    }
```

Everything is working except that I am still getting a redirect on successful login to root or the last endpoint that required authetication.

Can someone share how to properly configure Cookie Authentication.
I want to send credentials in Json and receive a Json response on success or error. And disable the redirection to the last attempted endpoint.

Comment: I have tried using `and().formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)` and extending `BasicAuthenticationFilter` but neither had an effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to configure the success handler on the `CustomAuthenticationProcessingFilter` filter, and not the `loginForm`

Configuring the custome filter resulted in the succss handler for the `loginform()` not being called at all.

`customAuthenticationProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(customeAuthenticationSuccessHandler());`